# Amazon MWS - how do I go about using AnyOfferChanged Notification with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-mws

I want to develop an app that sends me an email when pricing offers for specific listings change using the **AnyOfferChanged** MWS notifications. However, I can't find any good documentation on how to go about receiving the notifications. Is it a must to have AWS SQS, or can I use Django? how do I go about subscribing to a notification?

I already have a developers account and I'm using the python mws library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the [AnyOfferChangedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html) through the [Subscriptions API](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_Overview.html) and yes, it must use SQS.  I found it easiest to use the scratchpad to create the subscription, since it's usually a one-time event.

Once your price change notifications start flowing into your queue, write an app that reads the queue and you can respond to your messages, including sending an email if that's what you want to do.

See if these code samples for SQS help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-example_code-sqs.html